# Custom data binder in Spring 3 Controller

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, spring-3

A spring 2 way for registering a custom data binder in a controller would be to override the createBinder method of the extended spring controller. What is the spring 3 way of doing this? We use the @Controller annotation and therefore there is no hook i can override. I would have expected something like "@CreateBinder".

Searching the web wasn't very helpful. I only found [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?81209-Custom-DataBinder-in-Spring-3-0) related thread.

To make this clear: It's not about setting property editors. This I can do with @InitBinding.

Answer (score 1):

Use the @InitBinder annotation.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinderAll(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Country.class,  new CountryEditor());
}
```

Simon